# How do we set dynamic checkboxes to checked based on the value from the database in angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to reactive forms and struggling to set the *value* of the checkboxes to *true* dynamically.
Here's an example:
I am getting the pre-selected fruit values for a particular user from the db and those fruits need to be checked when the user loads the page.

I am using the below html code:

```
<ng-container>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="display: block;" *ngFor="let control of fruitsArray.controls; let i = index;">
  <input *ngIf="i<11" class="form-check-input" [formControl]="control" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox{{i}}" [checked]="fruitsCheck[i].checked">
  <label *ngIf="i<11" class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox{{i}}">{{fruitsCheck[i].label}} <br /></label>
</div>
```

fruitsCheck is an array of object which contains the label and the checked value as below:

```
fruitsCheck : Array<{label: string, checked: boolean}> = [];
```

fruitsCheck would hold values such as:

```
0: {label: "Apple", checked: true},
1: {label: "Orange", checked: false},
2: {label: "Pineapple", checked: true},
3: {label: "Kiwi", checked: false}
```

Using the above code, I am able to just set the appropriate checboxes as checked, but however upon checking the *value* of the specific checkbox control, it is still shown as *false*.I would like the checkbox not only to be checked, but also the control's value to be set to true.

I read about *patchValue* but unsure of how to use it to set the value to dynamic checkboxes.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ozeu59?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is a working example of populating a list of checkboxes in a reactive form.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public fruitsForm: FormGroup;

  get fruitsArray() : FormArray {
    return this.fruitsForm.get('fruits') as FormArray
  } 

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getFruits()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(fruits => {
        this.fruitsForm = this.fb.group({
          name: "Joe Bloggs",
          fruits: this.fb.array(fruits.map(f => this.fb.group(f)))
        });
      });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fruitsForm">
    <form [formGroup]="fruitsForm">
        <input name="name" formControlName="name" />
        <div formArrayName="fruits">
            <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruitsArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected" />
                <label>{{fruit.value.name}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br />
    <div>{{fruitsForm.value | json}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

We've simulated a fetch from the database using a service and the RxJS `delay` operator.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

interface Fruit {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor() {}

  public getFruits(): Observable<Fruit[]> {
    return of([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Apple",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Pear",
        selected: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Orange",
        selected: false
      }
    ]).pipe(delay(250));
  }
}
```

We use the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) service to build our form.

We bundle our controls into a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) called `fruitsForm`.

In our `FormGroup`, `fruits` is a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), allowing for many inputs.

Each `Fruit` object is mapped to a new `FormGroup`, and each property in our `Fruit` object will be converted into a `FormControl`.

The `fruitsArray` getter is to make it easier to access our form property.

To connect our template to the `FormArray`, we use the `formArrayName` directive.

The `formGroupName` directive uses the index find the correct `FormGroup` in our `fruits` `FormGroup`. To connect our checkbox to the `selected` control, we use the `formControlName` directive.